# How to make custom menu in website visible only for connected user? Odoo 16

Tags: xml, web, odoo

I added a menu to the website and I want only the connected user from the portal to see this menu.
I want to work with menus and not pages.

```
<record id="my_menu_website" model="website.menu">
    <field name="name">My Menu</field>
    <field name="url"></field>
    <field name="parent_id" ref="website.main_menu"/>
    <field name="sequence" type="int">2</field>
</record>
```

Any idea how to do this, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new field `group_ids` and override the[_compute_visible](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/addons/website/models/website_menu.py#L47) to set the `is_visible` field to `False` when a user is not a member of any group (The group must have an external ID)

***Example:***

```py
class Menu(models.Model):
    _inherit = "website.menu"

    group_ids = fields.Many2many("res.groups")
    
    def _compute_visible(self):
        for menu in self:
            visible = True
            group_external_ids = [xmlid for xmlid in menu.group_ids.get_external_id().values() if xmlid]
            if menu.group_ids and group_external_ids and not menu.user_has_groups(",".join(group_external_ids)):
                visible = False
            elif menu.page_id and not menu.user_has_groups('base.group_user'):
                page_sudo = menu.page_id.sudo()
                if (not page_sudo.is_visible
                    or (not page_sudo.view_id._handle_visibility(do_raise=False)
                        and page_sudo.view_id._get_cached_visibility() != "password")):
                    visible = False
            menu.is_visible = visible
```

*A group without an external xml id will be ignored